# Deploying NextJs static site in AWS (S3) with multiple pages

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-code-deploy

I have build one static website in NextJs and deploy in s3 bucket, It has multiple screens like (aboutus, contactus, etc...), but If I try to access aboutus like mys3bucketname/aboutus, it shows 404 Error, but If I try access it mys3bucketname/aboutus.html it's working, I don't want .html in my URL but need to access the screen.

Page should load using mys3bucketname/aboutus instead of mys3bucketname/aboutus.html

404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: aboutus
RequestId: R2HQZ4MAR0XC55J3
HostId: s5RfODIAEYfXeEV2MVUaPLS4aqAM3mfdOviSlYfNF3/1X7mzxiOJZqqOOvqvyotmS664gV0Gnyo=